# Inverse of an algebraic element over finite extension

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I am trying to understand finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ and I have to ask something little that I could not able to understand and may be trivial to you. I will write down few arguments and I would like to know whether they are correct or not and some $2$ related questions.
Now, let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$.Then,

*i*.$K$ is the smallest field containing both  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ and it is defined as $K:=\{\cfrac{a}{b}: b\neq 0, a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}\}$.

*ii.*$K$ can be considered as a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has a basis $\{1,\alpha_1,\dots\alpha_n\}$ so that any $x \in K$ can be written as $q_0+q_1\alpha_1 +q_2\alpha_2+\alpha_nq_n$ for some $q_1, \dots, q_n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

*iii*.$K$ as a vector space has to have dimension $n$ by definition of a finite extension but my basis has $n+1$ many elements, so what do I think wrong?

*iv*.How can I write the inverse of $\alpha_1$ with respect to my basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is the set of all rational *functions* of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, not just the *fractions* on them.

$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ does not in general have dimension $n$ over $\mathbb Q$ because $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ is not in general a *linear* basis.

If $\alpha$ is algebraic with minimal polynomial $a_n X^n + a_{n-1} X^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 X + a_0$, then $\alpha^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{-a_0}(a_n\alpha^{n-1}+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-2}+ \cdots +a_1)$. Note that $a_0\ne0$ because of minimality.

Comment: If we say that $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ are linearly independent, then do we have a linear basis? In this case, I think we should have:
$c_1\alpha_1 + \dots c_n\alpha_n = 0 \implies c_i = 0$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n$ where $c_i$'s belong to  $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Ninja, no. Try $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$. Then $1,\alpha$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ but $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ is.

Comment: Okay, one more question; if $\alpha \in K$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ s.t. its minimal polynomial has degree $n$, then can we say that $K$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$  which has dimension $n$ and basis $\{1,\alpha, \dots, \alpha^n\}?$

Comment: @Ninja, yes, but the basis goes only to $\alpha^{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you for all your effort, these are very helpful, I appreciate it!

Comment: It seems like I missed a point. For some $u \ge n$, how can I write $\alpha^{u}$ as "$\mathbb{Z}$-linear" combination of $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha^{n-1}\}$ and why do I need a "$\mathbb{Z}$-linear " combination?

Comment: I think you should expect $\alpha^u$ to be a $\Bbb Q$-linear combination of the basis elements.